# Hovering a link makes image slide out from nav bar with css3?

Tags: css

[JSFiddle of my failed attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/k2PA2/1/)

The idea is i have a nav bar, below it a footer. The links in the navbar have a featured image with them. When you hover the link, the image slides out from the nav bar.
This should be done CSS only.

HTML

```
<nav class="navigation">navbar
    <div class="singleelement">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title">
                Some Title1
            </div>
            <div class="titlepicture">some picture</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="singleelement">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title">
                Some Title2
            </div>
            <div class="titlepicture">some picture</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<footer>somefooter text </footer>
```

CSS

```
.titlepicture{
    background-color: green;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
}
.title{
    background-color: rgba(255, 235, 145, 0.60);

}
.container{
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition-property: all;
    -ms-transition-property: all;
    transition-property: all;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1.4s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 1.4s;
    transition-duration: 1.4s;
}
.container:hover{
    top: -100px;
}
.singleelement{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
nav {
    margin-top: 150px;
    background: aliceblue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this [codepen](http://codepen.io/the_ruther4d/pen/12a3a0e6f2e64f196e45b3959d66b771/). I've absolutely positioned the images and used css transforms to place them off-canvas, and transitions to bring them back in on hover. Something like this:

```
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: green;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

nav .singleelement {
  width: 50%;
  height: 60px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

nav .singleelement .titlepicture {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  z-index: -2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate3d(0, -200px, 0);
  transition: transform 0.25s ease;
}

nav .singleelement:hover .titlepicture {
  transform: translate3d(0, 60px, 0);
}
```

Comment: Nice demo: Just FYI, you should post your code in your answer.

Comment: Gotcha, I'll do that.

Comment: I want the title to move down together with the picture, can you get that to work?

Comment: Sure just add a transform to the `.singleelement` as well on hover

Comment: the order of the elements actually doesnt matter, i wanted it to go up. So you could exchange title and picture, doesnt matter